"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 85: invalid start byte" error when polygonizing WMS in QGIS
I am trying to polygonize a raster layer but I have an error. Here is the log:
QGIS version: 3.36.3-Maidenhead
QGIS code revision: 2df96554
Qt version: 5.15.13
Python version: 3.12.3
GDAL version: 3.9.0
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.4.0, March 1st, 2024
PDAL version: 2.6.3 (git-version: b5523a)
Algorithm started at: 2024-11-14T10:28:52
Algorithm 'Polygonize (raster to vector)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : 'DN', 'INPUT' : 'wms://crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=DANA2024.DelimitacionAreaInundadaUV&styles&tilePixelRatio=0&url=https://terramapas.icv.gva.es/00_DANA2024', 'OUTPUT' : 'F:/Users/i7-950/Box Sync/Projets QGIS/DANA/Flood_area/DANA.gpkg' }

GDAL command:
gdal_polygonize.bat "crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=DANA2024.DelimitacionAreaInundadaUV&styles&tilePixelRatio=0&url=https://terramapas.icv.gva.es/00_DANA2024" -b 1 -f "GPKG" "F:/Users/i7-950/Box Sync/Projets QGIS/DANA/Flood_area/DANA.gpkg" DANA DN
GDAL command output:
usage: gdal_polygonize.py [--help] [--help-general] [-q] [-8] [-o name=value] 
[-mask filename] [-nomask] [-b band] 
[-of ogr_format] [-lco name=value] [-overwrite] 
src_filename dst_filename [dst_layername] 
[dst_fieldname] 
gdal_polygonize.py: error: the following arguments are required: dst_filename
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 138, in on_stderr
val = ba.data().decode('UTF-8')
^^^^^^^
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 138, in on_stderr
val = ba.data().decode('UTF-8')
^^^^^^^
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 138, in on_stderr
val = ba.data().decode('UTF-8')
^^^^^^^
[Previous line repeated 1 more time]
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 107, in on_stdout
val = ba.data().decode('UTF-8')
^^^^^^^
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 138, in on_stderr
val = ba.data().decode('UTF-8')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 85: invalid start byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray'> returned a result with an exception set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray'> returned a result with an exception set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithm.py", line 133, in processAlgorithm
GdalUtils.runGdal(commands, feedback)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 154, in runGdal
res = proc.run(feedback)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SystemError: <built-in method run of QgsBlockingProcess object at 0x000001C62E471400> returned a result with an exception set

Execution failed after 1.79 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Polygonize (raster to vector)' finished

As the original source is in Spanish, I have removed letters with accents (see image below).

The URL for the WMS connection is this one.
Is the error caused by a typographical character or is the cause to be found elsewhere?

You cannot polygonize a WMS layer with QGIS. As you can see from the generated gdal_polygonize command, the name of the input raster is obscure.
"crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=DANA2024.DelimitacionAreaInundadaUV&styles&tilePixelRatio=0&url=https://terramapas.icv.gva.es/00_DANA2024"

What you can do is to save the screen that shows the WMS layer through Project - Import/Export - Export Map To Image. Then you can add the exported file back to QGIS as a normal raster layer and polygonize it.
